# Open third party application from browser

Tags: android, ios, schema

I want to open a cctv application, it is a third party app and I do not know its url schema. So how can I open it from a browser link "href" by only knowing its name ? and what if it does not have a url schema ?

I hope find a solution for both OS : Android / iOS

Here is a part of info.plist file for that application (For iOS)

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>prefs</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
    .
    .
    .
```

Thanks

Comment: Without the app URL scheme you will not be able to open it on iOS. But if you have the app (in iTunes) you can open the ipa and find the `config.plist` and look if there is an app URL scheme.

Comment: @rckoenes Do you mean "info.plist" ? cause no config.list at all !

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant info.plist